# stencil js, pass an array as attribute value in custom element

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs, tsx

I am looking for a way to pass an array as the value of an attribute of a web component made with stencil js. That's possible?

**I'm trying to make something like this works!**

index.html

```
<mv-select options=['one','two','three']></mv-select>
```

mv-select.tsx

```
@Component({
  tag: 'mv-select',
  styleUrl: 'mv-select.scss',
  assetsDirs: ['assets'],
    shadow: true
})
export class MvSelect {
  @Element() private element: HTMLElement;
  @Prop() options: string[];
```

Comment: Use ```JSON.stringify(arr)```.

Comment: https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript#passing-object-props-from-a-non-jsx-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that HTML attributes can only be strings, not arrays or objects. There are [a couple ways](https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript#passing-object-props-from-a-non-jsx-element) to pass an array:

1. Pass it as a property:

```js
document.querySelector('mv-select').options = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

2. Pass it as a JSON encoded string attribute:

```html
<mv-select options='["one", "two", "three"]'></mv-select>
```

To transform that JSON into an array you can use a `@Watch` method to update an internal `@State` property:

```
export class MvSelect {
  @Prop() options: string;
  @State() internalOptions: string[];

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.parseOptions();
  }

  @Watch('options')
  parseOptions() {
    if (this.options) {
      this.innerOptions = JSON.parse(this.options);
    }
  }
}
```

This code makes sure that whenever you change `options` it will be JSON parsed and you can use `innerOptions` as an array.

Note that you will have to manually call `this.parseOptions()` in `componentWillLoad` because the watchers are not called on initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It is written behind the proxy. So u can directly assign value in object.

**// Sample:**

```
var cmp = document.querySelector('my-comp');
cmp.data = arr; // arr is the array you are want to pass
```

**// Other Way:Pass as data string and parse**

```
export class TodoList {
  @Prop() name: string = 'Stencil';

  @Watch('name')
  validateName(newValue: string, oldValue: string) {
    const isBlank = typeof newValue == null;
    const has2chars = typeof newValue === 'string' && newValue.length >= 2;
    if (isBlank) { throw new Error('name: required') };
    if (!has2chars) { throw new Error('name: has2chars') };
  }
}
```

> **Ref:**

1. https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties#prop-decorator
2. https://medium.com/@gilfink/using-complex-objects-arrays-as-props-in-stencil-components-f2d54b093e85

Answer (score 0):

All things that you said are accurate, in HTML attribute only can be string that why array properties not working as expected (in Vue)...
However, we can apply generic solution like that;

```
function stringToArray<T>(arg: T[] | string): T[] {
  const opts = typeof arg === 'string'
    ? (arg as string)
        .split(',')
        .map(p => +p.trim())
        .filter(hasValue)
    : arg;

  return opts as T[];
}
```

And, also we should use related property with stringtoArray function like,

```
stringToArray<number>(options) // if options = [10,20,30]
stringToArray<string>(options) // if options = ['one','two',tree']
stringToArray<Date>(options)  // if option = [new Date.now(),new Date.now().addDay(1)
```

You can use this function for all array types